# missing sqlite3 history file

Tags: sqlite, cygwin, windows-console, input-history

I cannot find the command history created by `sqlite3`.

I have both `Windows` and `Cygwin` version.

Using the Windows binary, I can use up/down arrow to see previous commands, even from previous runs of command. But I can't find the file `.sqlite_history`. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306900/40620) answer suggests it should be in the home directory, but I can't find it there. I do have working a `.sqliterc` so I know it is the correct directory.

Using the Cygwin binary, I can't get the history to work at all. It seems history is not saved at all?

On the [documentation page](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) I cannot find any mention of history at all.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows console programs, the command history is handled by the Windows console itself. There are separate history buffers for different programs and different console sessions, and these buffers are not stored anywhere by default. However, you can use the [`doskey` tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753867.aspx) to manage them manually.

Cygwin uses Windows pipes to emulate the Unix `tty` devices; this often results in programs not detecting that they are running in a console. Try running the program both from within the Cygwin shell and from the Windows shell.

Comment: From `cmd.exe` I am running a `Windows` build of `sqlite3`, from `Cygwin` `xterm`/`tty` I am running a `Cygwin` build. 


I doubt windows console will preserve history across different invocations, which is what I see on Windows. 


I did try running Cygwin version from cmd.exe and windows version from bash, none of them generate the history file.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is just a program running in the console. See the section "Using doskey within a program" in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: Thanks CL. I am not sure you have understood my problem. As I wrote earlier, I do get persistent history on Windows, but I can't figure out where it is stored. So I don't see the point of doskey. I will leave you added tags, but my question is not about windows console, nor about general purpose input history, I am specifically interested in generating and locating the sqlite3 history file

Comment: The Windows history is *not* persistent; you'd have to use `doskey` to save it.

Comment: you are right. The history is persisted across different invocations of `sqlite3.exe` but not across different invocations of `cmd.exe`. In any case, I am looking for the history file from sqlite3, because I want to use the cygwin version. Thanks for your follow up.

Answer (score 2):

> The [SQLITE_HISTORY](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) environment variable, if it exists, specifies
> the name of the  command-line editing history file

> To repeat the last command, just press the ↑ key, to search for older
> ones — use Ctrl+R shortcut. History search It's faster to find a query than to type it again
>
> By default, SQLite stores the history file in the user’s home directory
> and names it `.sqlite_history` It’s in plain text, so you can view it
> in your favorite [editor](https://nano-editor.org). If you prefer to save it elsewhere, specify
> the full path in the `SQLITE_HISTORY` environment variable.
> source: https://antonz.org/sqlite-history

e.g:

```
cd ~
nano .sqlite_history
```

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html:

Comment: The file starts with the text '_HiStOrY_V2_'